# how to change width of list rows in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli

I'm using [Django Grappelli](https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.io/) for my Django admin theme, it works great but when I open a list of objects inside some modules it only takes about 25% of the width of the screen. check the screenshot

[image]

what ti need is to make it 100% width and remove this unused space

Answer (score 0):

It's not 25%, it's `width: auto`.

Just add to your `.css` file, used in admin:

```css
.result-list > table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]